# NSString UTF8String bad access

Tags: c++, ios, objective-c, nsstring

I need to convert an NSString to a std::string, and have done that successfully using `[str UTF8String]`. But for some reason when I try it on one of my NSStrings I get a `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` error.

I'm checking that `str` is not null, so I'm not sure why is this happening. I also tried making sure that `str` is indeed an NSString but the following throws the same error:

```
const char* className = class_getName([str class]);
```

What am I missing?

EDIT: The code I'm using:

```
NSMutableArray* m_imageInfos; // defined in ClassName.h
RUBEImageInfo *touchedImgInfo; // also defined in ClassName.h
```

This is a cocos2d project, and depending on the game flow I'm loading additional objects of type `RUBEImageInfo` into m_imageInfos. The relevant code:

```
RUBEImageInfo* imgInfo = [[RUBEImageInfo alloc] init];
imgInfo->sprite = sprite;
imgInfo->name = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:newImg->name.c_str()];
std::cout << "loadBody imgInfo name " << [imgInfo->name UTF8String] << "\n";
```

The std::cout prints out the image name correctly. I should add that the name is a concatenation of a string an an int, like this:

```
std::stringstream sstm;
sstm << img->name << counter;
newImg->name = sstm.str();
```

In ClassName.mm, CCTouchesBegun I check which b2Body is being touched, and then loop over m_imageInfos to see whicn imageInfo was touched:

```
for(int j=0; j<[m_imageInfos count]; j++) {
    RUBEImageInfo *rif = m_imageInfos[j];
    if(rif->body == body) {
        touchedImgInfo = rif;
        printf("ccTouchesBegun touchedImgInfo %p \n", touchedImgInfo);
        printf("ccTouchesBegun touchedImgInfo name %p \n", [touchedImgInfo->name UTF8String]);
            break;
     }
 }
```

The first printout passes well and gives a result like this:

```
ccTouchesBegun touchedImgInfo 0x98b84f0
```

But the second printout faults with `EXE_BAD_ACCESS`. To add complexity, this only happens most of the times. Once in every 10-15 attempts, it works fine.

For fullness of code, this is RUBEImageInfo.h:

```
#import "cocos2d.h"

@interface RUBEImageInfo : NSObject {

   @public CCSprite* sprite;               
   @public NSString* name;                 
   @public class b2Body* body;             
   @public float scale;                    
   @public float angle;                    
   @public CGPoint center;                 
   @public float opacity;                  
   @public bool flip;                      
   @public int colorTint[4];               
}

@end
```

Comment: So, does `std::string s([@"foo" UTF8String])` segfault as well?

Comment: What does `NSLog(@"%@", str)` do?  If it also seg faults, I'd say `str` is a zombie object.

Comment: Yes it faults on both. What does it mean a zombie object?

Comment: Show some actual code.  Where is the string defined.  Where is it assigned.  Where is it released?  Are you using ARC?

Comment: Really? `std::string s([@"foo" UTF8String])` segfaults? I find that really hard to believe, since a literal NSString like `@"foo"` is effectively interned and will never be released. It sure doesn't crash for me.

Comment: @Axeva the string is set like this: str = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:anotherStr.c_str()];

Comment: Again, can you please show the whole block of code.  How the string is assigned is only one part of the equation.  How it's allocated and how it's deallocated are also important.  Are you using ARC?

Comment: I'm not using ARC. The string is passed around a couple of times. I'll organize it tomorrow and post here.

Comment: I edited the question to provide the code.

Comment: Edited again, to provide even more code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
imgInfo->name = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:newImg->name.c_str()];
```

This is incorrect memory management. You're directly assigning an object you do not own to another object's instance variable. It will work if you use it in the same method, but the life of that object is not guaranteed past the life of the current autorelease pool. So eventually, the instance variable points to garbage.

Ideally, you should use accessors instead of assigning instance variables directly. That is the idiomatic approach in Cocoa apps. If you simply cannot use accessors for some reason, then you need to make absolutely sure you are managing your memory correctly everywhere the instance variable is used.

Comment: Thanks @Chuck. There aren't getters or setters in these objects, so how would you do the assignment?

Comment: @Eddy: You would release the current value (so as not to leak) and retain the new one if you don't already own it.

Comment: any chance for an example? I'm new to C++/Obj-C and this is still fuzzy for me. (I knew I'll miss Java at some point, probably sooner rather than later...)

Comment: I'm not sure how useful an example would be. `[obj retain]` and `[obj release]` would be the examples of how you retain and release things, but as you can see it won't lend a very deep understanding of anything. You might want to read Apple's [docs on memory management](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/MemoryMgmt.html) to get a better grasp of the concepts involved. BTW, whoever wrote this class you're using is apparently a mean, spiteful person, because I've never heard of a Cocoa class with no accessors.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that many classes in box2d also don't have accessors. But why are they important for memory management? Anyway thanks, I'll read the doc. I guess the concepts are similar for C++?

Comment: @Eddy: Accessors are important for memory management because they take care of it for you. They handle the retaining and releasing so that all memory management responsibility is local (and often automatic) rather than one piece of code being responsible for retaining and another much later needing to release. The Foundation framework was designed with that in mind.